# PCB Critique: Soft-start power distribution from 24V battery

Tags: power, pcb-design, circuit-design

### Design

[image: PCB design]

I'm designing a power supply to break out power from a 24V cordless battery that contains a 6s2p configuration of Samsung INR18650-20R cells ([datasheet, pdf](https://www.18650batterystore.com/v/files/samsung_20r_data_sheet.pdf)), each capable of 40A pulse and  22A continuous discharge. The power is broken out into three rails:

- Isolated 5V - 30W max, typically <2A
- Isolated 12V - 30W max, typically <<1A
- 24V - 10-30A continuous, 40A peak @ <10ms

Isolated circuits are provided by CUI's [PDQ30 series](https://www.cui.com/product/dc-dc-converters/isolated/pdq30-d-series). The reason for the soft-start is that the 24V rail will have **significant** bulk and downstream capacitance and requires a soft-start. The soft-start is based on TI's [LM5069](http://www.ti.com/product/LM5069) which uses a high-side FET ([nexperia PSMN1R0-40YSH](https://www.nexperia.com/products/mosfets/power-mosfets/PSMN1R0-40YSH.html)) to current-limit during startup. Plugs in lower left are for external SPST switches to allow separate power-up for isolated vs 24V (both have soft-start).

### Schematic

Nothing surprising here; mainly followed TI's Typical Application for the LM5069, with values approved by TI's [LM5069 calculator tool](http://www.ti.com/tool/LM5069QUICK-CALC). Happy to provide specific part numbers if desired.

[image: schematic]

### Layout

My main concern is layout, and whether the board will actually be able to supply these types of currents. 2-layer board, 92mm on a side. I've tried to make all the main power traces as large as possible to distribute current, as well as provide thermal sinking. All components aside from the spade terminals that connect it to the battery are on the top.

Top layer:

[image: Top]

Bottom layer:

[image: bottom]

Main concerns:

- Am I being too optimistic? Would this require something like a solid copper bus bar for the 24V rail?
- Considering I have three separate power rails on the top side, it's pretty hard to lay out the board in a way that allows there to be a ground plane on top.
- The current-sense resistor for the 24V is 1mOhm. It seems scary having 30A go through that small choke point, but at 30A that's only 0.9W and the datasheet suggests it's rated at 1W@70C, so that seems acceptable...? [PMR25HZPFV1L00 datasheet](https://www.rohm.com/datasheet/PMR18EZPFV/pmr-e)
- The ground plane is on the bottom layer, but I needed to get the bulk capacitance for the isolated DCDC converters connected to ground, so I put a 7x8 grid of vias in the upper left to try and spread the heat from both sides of the caps along the top copper traces. Is this useful?
- As above, I used 24 vias to bring the ground plane up to the circuits in the lower left.
- I'm also not using thermals for most of the connections, as I'm concerned that they'll heat up too much trying to dump that much current.

Any/all thoughts are much appreciated!

Edit: Added link to current sense resistor datasheet.

Comment: How much current does whatever port/connector in the bottom left corner draw/supply? Those two horizontal traces on the bottom layer should be avoided.

Comment: The two ports in the lower left are for switches to enable the isolated 5V/12V or the power 24V: combined they'll draw <1mA. Agreed that splitting the ground plane isn't ideal; was trying to keep it to a minimum. Is there another preferred route?

Comment: _" that's only 0.9W and the datasheet suggests it's rated at 1W@70C"_ - sounds iffy. Link to datasheet?

Comment: Added link to datasheet for sense resistor

Comment: Alright, that’s not much. I would still try to avoid that cut, preferably by layout itself, otherwise a jumper. Is this high volume by the way or why are you using just two layers?